# спрятать ссылку средствами javascript

Tags: javascript

Требуется спрятать ссылку от поисковых систем, с помощью javascript.
С целью более разумного распределения веса на странице

В сети, много примеров как это сделать с помощью jQuery, но требуется на чистом JS, потому как jQuery не дружит с используемым движком.

Comment: покажите нужный пример на jquery его вам переделают на JS

Comment: [Hide links from Google via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826800/hide-links-from-google-via-javascript)

Comment: Для таких задач используется rel="nofollow".

Answer (score 3):

Достаточно указать в ссылке аттрибут `rel="nofollow"`, уже давно все основные поисковики его обрабатывают.

Так же в поисковиках можно через SiteMap вручную настраивать вес страниц внутри сайта.

Вес указывается в эллементе `<priority>0.7</priority>`

Смотрите https://www.sitemaps.org/ru/protocol.html

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, активируйте ссылку событием `onclick=`, которому назначьте функцию, а в функции соберите ссылку из разных строк, прописанных в переменных, посредством конкатанации, и используйте этот "пазл" в качестве адреса в `window.open()`. Так ссылку никакой поисковик не найдёт. ))

Answer (score 0):

Можешь закинуть на нужные тэги, **span**, например, атрибут **data-url** (или любой другой) и какой-нибудь класс, например, **my-link**

```
<span class="my-link" data-url="http://google.com/">Ссылка</span>
```

И обработать переход через JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my-link').forEach(function(link) {
  link.onclick = function() {
    window.open(link.dataset.url); // Если хочешь открыть новую вкладку
    location.href = link.dataset.url; // Если хочешь перейти по ссылке в этой вкладке
  };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

если поместить URL в скрипт то она будит спрятана от поисковых систем

```
<a href='javascript: document.location.href = "http://www.yandex.ru";'>
ссылка спрятана от поисковых систем</a>
```

можно вынести за пределы тега

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function fu_href(){
//  перейти по ссылке в текущем окне
//  document.location.href = "http://www.yandex.ru"
//   Открыть  урл  в новом окне
window.open("http://yandex.ru");
}

/*
    Можно попробовать вариант добавления ссылки в тело HTML документа по
 средствам стандартных методов  библиотеки яваскрипта в  браузера 
*/
// небольшой ХАРДКОР
var arr = ["h","t","t","p:","//"]
var arr_1 = ["W","W","W"]
var arr_2 = ["."]
var yandex_arr = ["Y","A","N","D","E","X"]
var arr_4 = ["r","u"]

var teg_A = document.createElement("A")
    teg_A.setAttribute("href", "#")

    teg_A.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ссылка добавленная
 яваскриптом спрятана от поисковых систем"))    
    teg_A.onclick = function(){window.open(arr.concat(arr_1,arr_2,yandex_arr,arr_2,arr_4)
.join("").toLowerCase()); return false}
//добавляем тег А с набором параметров, в  тега BODY, последним узлом
    document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].appendChild(teg_A) 
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="fu_href(); return false">ссылка спрятана от
 поисковых систем</a>
</br>
```